# editing revit files in forge viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I wanted to make changes in SVF file using Forge viewer but couldn't find any useful resource.
Two more questions.

1. how to sync this changes with local copies.
2. how to convert SVF to RVT, if possible.

In this project i am using plain JavaScript and HTML, Please lead me to correct resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the viewer is a viewer and not an editor. It means you cannot save changes in either SVF or RVT format. You can save your edits/changes into an external database and re-apply them on reloading.

The Model Derivative API, is extracting data to SVF, but this is a one way process. You cannot go back to RVT today.

However, while extracting RVT data to SVF, the objects' GUID are extracted, meaning you can identify objects in BOTH Revit and SVF, so you could write a Revit plugin to read your database containing your edits and apply these changes to Revit elements using Design Automation.